# Localhost 3000 cant make request to localhost 8000

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost, mern

Hello everyone after last time I decided to refactor my code and my question. I am running a React app on localhost 3000 and a node server on port 8000. And for some reason when I try to make request to port 8000 It always hits port 3000 which can be seen on dev tools request headers like - Request URL: http://localhost:3000/. Here is what my simple node app looks like -

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';

// APP
const app = express();
// CORS
app.use(cors());
// LOG EVRY REQ
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ key: 'success' });
});
// CONFIG
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

const port = 8000;

// STARTING APP

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening the port 127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
});
```

And in react I set proxy property to http://localhost:8000

How can I set up node and react in my localhost?

You can see all the code in my GitHub - https://github.com/SalehBal/NodeToDo

Comment: I don't get it.  This app listens on port 8000.  If you access `http://localhost:8000` then your app responds correctly.  So what exactly do I have to do to reproduce your issue?  What do you mean "I am running a React app on localhost 3000"?

Comment: node app runs on port 8000 and I have added proxy as Request URL: http://localhost:8000/ which will result in react sending req to this URL "supposed to" but it doesn't. How can I set up a mern app on localhost

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are requesting `/` or more specifically `http://localhost:3000/`.  This is a static resource that is served by the *create-react-app* infrastructure.  In fact `/` is your main page.  If `/` were proxied to your backend, your browser would never be able to fetch the page itself.

Instead, the `proxy` feature of *create-react-app* is designed to proxy any **unknown** endpoints.  But `/` is a **known** request.  [Read the create-react-app docs about this here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Some other verboten non-proxied endpoints that are served up by your create-react-app server itself:

- `/static/js/bundle.js`
- `/manifest.json`
- `/favicon.ico`
- `/ws`
- `/logo192.png`

To get your app working.  Change your backend to serve up a different route - one that is different from any resource that is part of the app itself.  For example:  change `/` to `/api`

```js
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ key: 'success' });
});
```

and in your frontend, you can fetch `/api`.  e.g.:

```
fetch('/api', {})
```

Everything should work then.

Answer (score -1):

I have modified the file (`/frontend/src/utils/callApi.js`) as followed.

```
function callApi(path, method, body, sucess, fail) {
  fetch("https://localhost:8000" + path, {    // <--- changed from "" to "https://localhost:8000"
    // headers: {
    //   Authorization: 'Basic SGVsbG8gdGhlcmUgOikgSGF2ZSBhIGdvb2QgZGF5IQ==',
    //   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    // },
    // body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });
}
export default callApi;
```

Of course, you can set the domain(`"https://localhost:8000"`) as the parameter and save it in the `.env` file.
Hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: That's not a proxied (same origin) call.  That's a cross-origin call.